# Find a continuous function $f$ that satisfies...

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Find a continuous function $f$ that satisfies

$$
f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}\int_1^x f(t) \ dt
$$

Note: I tried differentiating with respect to $x$ to get an ODE but you get one that contains integrals - likely difficult to solve.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$ supposed to be?

Comment: I downvoted because this post "does not show any research effort."  I would upvote if you explained what motivated you to ask the question, what efforts you have used to try to solve it that didn't work, etc...

Comment: Also, have you tried differentiating with respect to $x$?

Comment: Not specified in the problem statement - I would assume it to be all real numbers

Comment: @Ryan $x=0{}{}$?

Comment: If you differentiate with respect to $x$, which was what I tried first, you get a differential equation that contains integrals so solving it could prove to be quite tricky.

Comment: @GitGud I was looking at that too, but I suppose the problem is nice enough that the integral goes to zero there and cancels it.

Comment: @Potato It could be that the limit is well-behaved, but it still is undefined at $x=0$

Comment: @RyanPeden The integral is the one that already appears in the problem, so you can substitute to remove it. There are cleverer solutions below, though.

Comment: @GitGud Oh, come on, are we really going to get pedantic about removable singularities?

Answer (score 13):

**Hint:** $xf(x) = x + \int_1^x f(t) \, dt $, except possibly at $x=0$.

Differentiate this to conclude that $f(x) = \ln x + C $.

Evaluate at $x=1$.

Answer (score 6):

I will also assume that $f$ is differentiable. We are given that $f(x)=1+\frac{1}{x} \int_1^xf(t)dt$. Multiplying by $x$ we see that
$$xf(x)=x+\int_1^xf(t)dt$$
Differentiating,
$$f(x)+xf'(x)=1+f(x)$$
Subtracting $f(x)$ then dividing through by $x$,

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$

Now, integrating we obtain

$$f(x)=\ln(x)+C$$

We must now deal with the initial conditions. from the original condition that $f(1)=1$. So,
$$f(1) = 1 =\ln(1)+C \implies C=1$$

Thus the only continuous (+differentiable) function that satisfies the given condition is 
$$f(x)=\ln(x)+1.$$

Comment: $ \ln( 0 ) + C = 0 \implies C = 0$?

Comment: @Lucas My mistake, but an easy fix.

Comment: I believe you meant to write that $ f\(1\) = 1 $ (and that $ f\(1\) = 1 = \ln\(0\) + C \implies C = 1 $)?

Comment: Good catch! I really should have been more careful and checked to see if the solution I provided worked. You are entirely correct.

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle F(x) = \int_1^xf(t) dt$

So

$\displaystyle \frac{dF}{dx} = 1 + \frac{1}{x} F$

with condition $F(1)=0$

Answer (score 1):

Given that

$$f(x)=1+\frac{1}{x}\int_1^x f(t)dt$$ Differentiating both sides

$$ f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}f(x)-\frac{1}{x^2}\int_1^xf(t)dt$$
 $\implies$

$$ f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}f(x)-\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{x}\int_1^xf(t)dt\right)$$ But

$$\frac{1}{x}\int_1^x f(t)dt=f(x)-1$$ So
$$f'(x)=\frac{f(x}{x}-\frac{1}{x}\left(f(x)-1\right)$$ $\implies$

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x} \implies f(x)=Ln(x)+c $$ Finally Use $f(1)=1$ to get the value of $c$